Read Excel in Databricks without Account Key
On databricks I Installed the following package
com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.5

My code looks like the following
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
.option("header", "false") \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \
.option("dataAddress", "Version") \
.load('abfss://abc.xlsx')

In my Cluster Config I have the config for a Service principal:
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret {{secrets/xx}}
fs.azure.account.auth.type OAuth
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/0x/oauth2/token
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client

I get the following error:
Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

How can I access that data without account key?

Works also without account key. Just set:
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret 
fs.azure.account.auth.type OAuth
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled 
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint 
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id 5

Important: completely restart the cluster so that the changes are applied
